# Get an attribute from a node using another "multi-values"attribute XML/XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I don't understand how to reach an attribute searching for a "multi-values" attribute.

I'll write down an example from W3school

[link: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp ]

```
<bookstore>
<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

How can I get, for example, the title searching with the string `<xsl:value-of "/bookstore/book[author = James McGovern]/title"/>`.

Can someone help me? I'm new to use XML and XSL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful with your terminology. In your XML only `category` and `lang` are attributes. On the otherhand `author` is an element. So, what you are really asking is how to match when multiple child elements have the same name.

The answer is to do exactly what you are trying to do already, expect you just need to put your author name in apostrophes to indicate it is a string literal

```
<xsl:value-of select="/bookstore/book[author = 'James McGovern']/title"/>
```

When you have an expression like `author = 'James McGovern'` it will actually check all `author` elements, and return true if at least one match. So it will still return true even if "James McGovern" is the last author listed.

(If you want to learn more, you can read up on boolean expressions in the official W3C specification at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#booleans. In particular, this case is covered by the line "*If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-value of the node and the other string is true*")